# echo result as part of bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to use this code in order to echo some information, which is required to have a bind_param, in order to generate the data.  What changes do I need to make to this code in order to get it to work?

```
function get_header_link($sql, $image)
{
    include 'connect.php';

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $select = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $select->bind_param('s', $id);
    if ($result = $select->execute()) {
        foreach($select as $value => $row) {
            echo "<h4>" . $row['display'] . "</h4>\n
                    <div class='placeholder' id='large'>\n
                        <img src='" . $row[$image] . "'/>\n
                        <div class='name'>
                            <h1>" . $row['display'] . "</h1>\n
                        </div>
                  </div>";
        }
    }
}
```

On running the code above, using:

```
get_header_link("SELECT * FROM homelinks WHERE linkID=?", "large_image");
```

I no longer get an error, and none of the data from the database is printing.

Comment: Currently you execute your query twice. Once in the prepare form once without. Drop the line with `$conn->query()`.

Comment: Did that change but  got an error stating that "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevelopment\AfterGlowWebsite\functions.php on line 252->if ($result->num_rows > 0) {"

Comment: after just deleting the line, $result will not be defined. Then the proper way is `$result = $select->execute();` instead of simple `$select->execute();`

Comment: @sirko - line has been dropped however nothing gets displayed now.

Comment: @random: did that but I get this error message:  **Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevelopment\AfterGlowWebsite\functions.php on line 251->if ($result->num_rows > 0) {**

Comment: So the if must be : `if($result = $select->execute();) {`

Comment: still doesn't work :( - and I'm getting an error message stating that the ; is extra.

Comment: remove the `;`... my fault... there is no `;` in a if...

Comment: @Random : even if I remove the ; the code still give me an error, **Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevelopment\AfterGlowWebsite\functions.php on line 251 -> referring to if ($result->num_rows > 0) { **

Comment: That's a weird behavior. It should work with mysqli... what is `connect.php` (and so, what is `$conn` ?) Isn't it some custom code.... ?

Comment: @Random: Posted the code for connect.php in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/994070/4786273), you should use `mysqli` like this:

```
function get_header_link($sql, $image)
{
    include 'connect.php';

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $select = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $select->bind_param('s', $id);
    $select->execute();
    $select->store_result();
    $meta = $select->result_metadata();
    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
        $params[] = & $row[$field->name];
    }

    // bind all columns in $row
    call_user_func_array(array(
        $select,
        'bind_result'
    ) , $params);

    while ($select->fetch()) {
        echo "<h4>" . $row['display'] . "</h4>\n
                <div class='placeholder' id='large'>\n
                    <img src='" . $row[$image] . "'/>\n
                    <div class='name'>
                        <h1>" . $row['display'] . "</h1>\n
                    </div>
                </div>";
    }

    /* close statement */
    $select->close();
}
```

Comment: No longer getting errors but I'm getting a blank div

Comment: what do you mean by that? as I am not the best with regards to terminology

Comment: Thanks alot for the help, the answer you posted was super helpful.  However it needed a minor change in order to work.

Comment: I edited answer to contain the correct answer, nice it works

Comment: Edited the answer to check for empty rows, in case it is needed.

Comment: @Chri Is there really an issue if the result is empty ? Everything is in a while. I think fetch accepts empty result, so it would only not run the loop. Don't you agree ? I added store_result which may be useful indeed.

Comment: In this situation no, however if there is data which is echoed before the while, checking for empty rows will prevent it from echoing if there are no rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_header_link($sql)
{
    include 'connect.php';

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $select = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $select->bind_param('s', $id);
    $select->execute();
    $meta = $select->result_metadata();
    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
        $params[] = & $row[$field->name];
    }

    call_user_func_array(array(
        $select,
        'bind_result'
    ) , $params);
    while ($select->fetch()) {
        echo "<h4>" . $row['display'] . "</h4>\n
            <div class='placeholder' id='large'>\n
                <img src='" . $row['large_image'] . "'/>\n
                <div class='name'>
                    <h1>" . $row['display'] . "</h1>\n
                </div>
          </div>";
    }

    $select->close();
}
```

Comment: It gave me the results I was going for :) I think the $row is indirectly affected by fetch somehow.

Comment: Indeed, it comes from `$params[] = &$row[$field->name]`, and then the call to `bind_result` which put the result in row variable...