# Updating to Prepared mysqli SELECT statement - it does not find the row

Tags: php, select, mysqli

I was advised to update my code to prevent sql injections. So here is what I have.

**VARIABLE FROM URL**

```
$Idarticle = "5-6142-8906-6641";
```

**THIS WORKS - OLD**

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE IDArticle IN ('{$Idarticle}')";
$results2 = $conn->query($sql2);
$row2 = $results2->fetch_assoc();
```

**THIS DOES NOT WORK - NEW**

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE IDArticle IN ( ? )";
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql2)) {
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $Idarticle);
  $stmt->execute();
  $row2 = $stmt->fetch();
}
```

**MY CONNECTION SCRIPT**

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
```

In the second example I get no results(no errors either) verses in the first it finds the correct row. I have read numerous similar questions previously asked and while there may be an answer out there, I did not find it. I also tried some of those answers without any success. I appreciate any help.

**UPDATED CODE PER COMMENTS**

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE IDArticle = ?";
if (!$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql2)) {
    if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $Idarticle));
    echo "error: " . $stmt->error;
    if (!$stmt->execute());
    echo "error: " . $stmt->error;
    $row2 = $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Still not finding the record / no errors being reported

**MY SOLUTION**

Having spent close to two days researching and trying to solve this issue, I decided mysqli was at the heart of the problem. Why I am sure this issue does have a solution with mysqli, I ended up moving to PDO. I resisted doing this initially but after a few hours of study, it is in my opinion, as well as many others, far better. Bottom line it now works flawlessly with very few changes. My recommendation, If you are struggling with mysqli, switch to PDO.

**A BIG THANK YOU TO THOSE WHO TRIED TO HELP**

Comment: The old code can't work because `$results2` is not `$results1` so you should probably fix that typo.

Answer (score 0):

BTW: Is there any special reason for using IN?

```
"SELECT * FROM articles WHERE IDArticle = ?"
```

Comment: Curly braces aren't helping here. The reason op is using IN is because he's trying to pull records from multiple posts.

Comment: $Idarticle = "5-6142-8906-6641"; from the question is a single value, not a list. `('{$Idarticle}')` adds braces to the parameter in the working example.

Comment: Ah, you may be right about the IN. But the curly braces are for php variable expansion, and incorrect in your usage.

Comment: I tried the brackets but throws up an error - can not pass parameter by reference(referring to that line number. As far as IN, that was a remnant from the old script. Be right back, have to walk the dog.

Comment: Ok based on comments I got rid of the brackets and IN. Back to where I started. No records no errors.

Comment: I now have... WHERE IDarticle = ?"

Comment: Still it's not even near to being an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
$row2 = $stmt->fetch();
```

[`mysqli_stmt::fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) returns boolean true/false on success, and you're trying to use it as an array for `row2`

You must bind your results first with [`mysqli_stmt::bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php), and then `fetch`

See [this creative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/994070/4233593) for how to get an associative array from `bind_result`

Preferably, if you have the [MySQL native driver](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) installed, then you can extract this directly with [`mysqli_stmt::get_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

---

Also, you're not checking for statement errors.

```
if ( !$stmt->bind_param("s", $Idarticle) )
    echo "error: " . $stmt->error;

if ( !$stmt->execute() )
    echo "error: " . $stmt->error;
```

And you should make sure you're using [PHP error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php).

Comment: `$Idarticle = "5-6142-8906-6641"`; that's no integer ;)  but if - you were right.
Anyway error checking is a always good practice. Thanks for undodownvote.

Comment: @lexx LOL you're all over this one! I shouldn't be doing this from my phone. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that and follow up

Comment: So I added error checking and I get no errors and it still is not finding any results. At this point I'm thinking this is a dead horse. It ain't going anywhere. Appreciate your time and thoughts.

Comment: @Spaceman OK, I finally got to a real computer and loaded this up. The problem is really obvious now, and I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Jeff Puckett II thanks for your continued efforts. I'll tackle this with a fresh mind and a cup of coffee in the morning.

Answer (score -1):

If $results1/$results2 is not a typo, then the new code is very different, because there must be two independent queries.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE IDArticle IN ( ? )";
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql2)) {
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $Idarticle);
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

But it's not clear then what was done with $results2 later in the code. row2 might be totally unrelated to

```
$row2 = $results1->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: Very sorry for the confussion on results1 that was a typo in my question but not in my working example. I corrected the question.

Comment: @spaceman: NP, did you try the =? variant?
Otherwise stay almost with the original code but 
`$IdarticleEscaped=mysqli_real_escape_string($Idarticle);
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE IDArticle IN ('{$IdarticleEscaped}')";`

Comment: Yes i did try =?. Your solution of sanitizing the variable was my original thought before posting this question, but I figured what the he let me give the other a try. Hours later I'm still thinking. I'm going to put error checking in as suggested by Puckett.